# Why can't I pipe awk outputs into a variable via >

Tags: bash, awk

I am trying to pipe awk output into a variable like this:

```
$ awk -F : '/frost/{print $3}' /etc/group > $mygid
$ echo $mygid
$
```

But when I want to see the `mygid` variable it just hangs. I had to do it like this:

```
$ "$(awk -F : '/frost/{print $3}' /etc/group)"
```

to get it to work.

I don't understand why.

Thanks

Comment: Hmm. We have another question with the same misconception in the knowledgebase, but it's not an easy one to search for.

Comment: If you're going to use `bash`, then you really should read the manual. In a Terminal, `man bash` or [Bash Reference Manual in HTML](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html) or [Bash Reference Manual PDF](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.pdf)

Answer (score 3):

`>` writes into a *file*.  `> $mygld` tries to write into a file named whatever is currently in the variable `$mygid`.

To get output of a command in a variable, you can use command substitution and assignment, or process substitution and `read`:

```
mygid=$(awk -F : '/frost/{print $3}' /etc/group)
```

or

```
read mygid < <(awk -F : '/frost/{print $3}' /etc/group)
```

I recommend you read some basic shell programming tutorials, perhaps http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide